# Loading polygons from MongoDB that entirely contain a known polygon

Tags: c#, mongodb, geojson

We have a set of GeoJsonPolygons stored in MongoDB and we're using C# to interact with Mongo.

Previously we were loading polygons which contained a `GeoJson.Point` by using:

```
var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(known.Longitude, known.Latitude));
var query = Query<OurStoredPolygons>.GeoIntersects(x => x.Polygon, point);
var polygonsThatContainTheKnownPoint = collection.FindAs<OurStoredPolygons>(query);
```

Now I want to load polygons if another known polygon is entirely within them. I can do the similar operation:

```
var linearRingCoordinates = new GeoJsonLinearRingCoordinates<GeoJson2DCoordinates>(coordinates);
var polygonCoordinates = new GeoJsonPolygonCoordinates<GeoJson2DCoordinates>(linearRingCoordinates);
var geoCircle = new GeoJsonPolygon<GeoJson2DCoordinates>(polygonCoordinates);
var query = Query<OurStoredPolygons>.GeoIntersects(x => x.Polygon, geoCircle);
var geofences = collection.FindAs<OurStoredPolygons>(query);
```

But this query will load any polygon that overlaps or even shares an edge at all with the test point. And I only want polygons that entirely contains the test point.

I suppose I could test every point in the polygon edge to load polygons that contain it and then reduce the results to only stored polygons common to every result but that seems like a potentially very slow operation (with a large test polygon and many polygons in the DB)

Is it possible to make that query in Mongo? (or indeed in C#)

Comment: Are all of the polygons convex or is there the possibility that they can be concave?

Comment: @SteveLillis the test polygon will always be convex (it should always be an approximate circle) but the stored polygons can be concave.

Comment: I have a slightly different problem.  Can you show how to get "coordinates" from a geoJson polygon string?

Comment: Hi @Lereveme you should open a new question rather than ask questions in the comments (otherwise you won't get answers)

Comment: It should be trivial to get the coordinates from a polygon string as it's just formatted coordinates. feel free to comment here when you've added a question and I'll look