# Mongo C# Driver - GeoJson Polygon to GeoJsonLinearRingCoordinates<GeoJson2DCoordinates>

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongo-c-driver, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to the Mongo C# driver and I'm trying to create a intersect query in C#.  I have the function working in Javascript but I'm struggling with some of the classes in the Mongo driver.

At the moment I have the GeoJson pulling fine but when I go to create the object to pass to the intersect query I don't seem to have the right parameters.  At the moment I'm using the following post to model my filter:  [Loading polygons from MongoDB that entirely contain a known polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620617/loading-polygons-from-mongodb-that-entirely-contain-a-known-polygon)

How can I convert a geojson string to a list of "coordinates" to create the GeoJsonLinearRingCoordinates object?

Here is an example of a polygon that I'm trying to use (Carroll county Ohio):

```
{[  [    
  [      -80.861994,      40.599404    ],    
  [      -80.863567,      40.555411    ],    
  [      -80.92092,      40.556315    ],    
  [      -80.924566,      40.467975    ],    
  [      -80.940153,      40.468349    ],    
  [      -80.941911,      40.4247    ],    
  [      -81.100097,      40.428928    ],    
  [      -81.212309,      40.433457    ],    
  [      -81.269951,      40.433486    ],    
  [      -81.264744,      40.565042    ],    
  [      -81.321659,      40.566648    ],    
  [      -81.317739,      40.651579    ],    
  [      -81.24125,      40.650534    ],    
  [      -81.237227,      40.723542    ],    
  [      -81.198599,      40.729172    ],    
  [      -81.087289,      40.727816    ],    
  [      -80.917172,      40.726934    ],    
  [      -80.918125,      40.643464    ],    
  [      -80.860822,      40.64257    ],    
  [      -80.861994,      40.599404    ]  
]]}
```

And here is my JavaScript query that I'm using in the Mongo shell:

```
db.MapPoints.find({ "GeoPoint.coordinates": { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: region.GeoJson.geometry } } })
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick modification of the Mongo driver test class to get the object I needed to move forward.  I'm not sure if this is going to work for all of my polygons but it is getting past the current problem.  If anyone else has a better way to do this please share.  Thanks!

```
    private GeoJsonPolygon<GeoJson2DCoordinates> GetMongoPolygon(string json)
    {
        return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<GeoJsonPolygon<GeoJson2DCoordinates>>(json);
    }
```